# Multiple Queries in one Report (Visual Studio 2005)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

So I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and trying to create ONE report with MULTIPLE queries in the report.

All queries have the same number of columns (and column names) but slight tweaks, etc. within each query (so they're basically all different).

I'm not entirely sure how I can get these multiple queries to appear in one report

Would really appreciate all and any help!

Comment: You can use UNION ALL, I guess?

You can find [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) reference valuable.

Comment: The problem with using the union is just as you stated - it combined all the info into ONE table.  When I actually want to keep the info in separate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [add multiple Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167503(v=sql.90).aspx) to a report, each pointing to a [different Dataset](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160345(v=sql.90).aspx). Just make sure the `DataSetName` property of the Table points right Dataset.

Comment: I've actually tried doing this with multiple dataset but I never got/understood how to make different areas of the report point to different datasets.

Comment: Just add 2 Tables, each pointing to a different Dataset by setting the DataSetName property of the table to the correct Dataset.

Comment: I only ever got it to work for aggregate functions (sum, etc.)

Comment: Just saw above comment - I'll see if it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple result sets with `UNION` into one single result set.

For using `UNION` you need to cover two basic rules

1. The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all
   queries.
2. The data types must be compatible.

The query you are going to have is something like this

```
{Query 1}

UNION [ALL]

{Query 2} 

UNION [ALL]

{Query 3}
```

Comment: The problem with using the union is just as you stated - it combined all the info into ONE table.  When I actually want to keep the info in separate tables.  

And display the info separately in the report.